# Myanmar language regular expression showing unwanted character

Tags: php, regex, unicode, preg-replace, combining-marks

```
$result = ဖန္တ

$result = preg_replace(
            "/([\p{L}\p{N}A-Za-z0-9@#\".]{1,}[\p{L}\p{N}A-Za-z0-9\.\_-]{0,})/u",
            "foo[('$0')]bar",
            $result);

print_r($result);

//RESULT: foo[('ဖန')]bar္foo[('တ')]bar
```

See `bar္foo` in there?  I don't know why I am seeing this junk character? How to removed it? But if I use `hello world` as the input string, then it's showing the expected result:

```
foo[('hello')]bar foo[('world')]bar
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `MYANMAR SIGN VIRAMA` "combining mark" falls outside of the character class that you have written.

If you were to execute:

```
var_dump(preg_split('//u', $input, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

You would see that the individual characters in the string are: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6Wgak))

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "ဖ"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "န"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "္"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "တ"
}
```

If you just want to replace combining marks with spaces, then make a second pass over the string to remove them.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/c3bJB))

```
$input = 'ဖန္တ';

echo preg_replace(
         ['/[\p{L}\p{N}@#".]+[\p{L}\p{N}._-]*/u', '/\p{M}/u'],
         ["foo[('$0')]bar", ' '],
         $input
     );
```

Output:

```
foo[('ဖန')]bar foo[('တ')]bar
```